# UIButton with rounded corners allows interaction in the corners

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a button that I am creating in Interface Builder. I am setting its corner radius and masksToBounds in Interface Builder as well:

[image: Runtime Attributes]

Essentially these settings make the button round. This clips my button correctly; however, the corners are still interactive.

How can I make the interaction stay within the layer as well?

Here's a screenshot of my button:

[image: Button Screenshot]

My button is the red circle. I've put a light grey UIView behind it to show the area where it still responds to touches.

Comment: add a screenshot of the button

Comment: @Fry added. any ideas on the fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can subclass the UIButton;

in `– (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` check if touch point is inside the area we are interested in, otherwise return nil.
More about this here: http://www.planet1107.net/blog/custom-shape-uibutton-tutorial/

Or ... more simple.. use this https://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton

**update** - with @jancakes's note:

*one note on that github project: the button will only respond to touches in non-transparent part of the image, so if the image relies heavily on transparency inside, then the implementation in the tutorial is the more useful approach

Comment: one note on that github project: the button will only respond to touches in non-transparent part of the image, so if the image relies heavily on transparency inside, then the implementation in the tutorial is the more useful approach

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that when you using the property `backgroundColor` this is the behavior.
For avoid this, just using an `UIImage` as background of the button.

Create a circle image with transparent content around an set as background, this works for me.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I have set the background color to [UIColor clearColor] and have tried setting an image both as image and as backgroundImage (not at the same time). The behaviour didn't change.